# How to achieve thread synchronization in two C++11 Threads?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-synchronization

**Situation:**

A `Factory` class member function `manager` spawns two `worker` threads. Each `worker` thread run a loop for each day of an year, and increment their own var `workHours`, and a shared var `work`. At the end of each day, each `worker` thread signals `manager` to get their report of `work` and `workHours`
When the `manager` gets `workHours` from both the `worker` threads, it reports `totalWorkHours` as (`workHours[0] + workHours[1]`) to the `boss`

**Problem:**

Threads are not working as expected. Threads are running in multiple loops before reporting to the manager. They are not synced for each day reporting. 
How to achieve this thread syncing, that after each day, both threads report their stats to manager.

**Code:**

[The below code is has no compile errors, in case you want to test run, edit]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class Factory{

public:
    Factory() {
        work = 0; 
        workHours[0] = 0; 
        workHours[1] = 0;
    };
    void manager();

private:
    std::thread threads[2];
    std::mutex m_lock;
    std::condition_variable cond[2];

    int work;               // Shared across threads
    int workHours[2];       // One var for each thread
    int totalWorkHours;

    void worker(int id);
    void boss(int work, int workHours);
};

void Factory::worker(int id)
{
    cout<< id <<" Started Working "<<endl;
    for (int day = 0; day<365; day++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ m_lock };
        work++;
        workHours[id]++;
        cout << id << " working " << endl;
        cond[id].notify_one();
        lck.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}


void Factory::manager()
{
    int wHrs0, wHrs1;

    threads[0] = std::thread([&](Factory *fac) { fac->worker(0); }, this);
    threads[1] = std::thread([&](Factory *fac) { fac->worker(1); }, this);

    //for (int day=0; day<365; day++)
    for (;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> lck0{ m_lock };
        cond[0].wait(lck0);
        cout << "Worker0 workHours : " << workHours[0] << "  Total Work : " << work << endl;
        wHrs0 = workHours[0];
        lck0.unlock();

        std::unique_lock<mutex> lck1{ m_lock };
        cond[1].wait(lck1);
        cout << "Worker1 workHours : " << workHours[1] << "  Total Work : " << work << endl;
        wHrs1 = workHours[1];
        lck1.unlock();

        totalWorkHours = wHrs0 + wHrs1;

        cout << "Both Workers Worked one day" << endl;
        boss(work, totalWorkHours);
    }
}

void Factory::boss(int work, int workHours)
{
    cout << "I am not Happy with just " << work << " amount of work in damn " << workHours << " Hrs " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Factory nike;
    nike.manager();

    //wait for keypress
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to unlock the lock before the sleep in your `worker` loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for the comment. I did that (updated the question as well), still not synced properly.

Comment: In the limit, `worker(1)` can run all 365 iterations of the loop before `manager` ever gets to `cond[1].wait(lck1);` - there's nothing stopping it. I don't see any attempt to synchronize workers to any particular event or condition.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Can you suggest any synchronization method for this ? i cant use posix semaphore (want to keep this platform independent).

Comment: A condition variable is normally associated with some condition; hence the name. You are supposed to wait on it until some condition becomes true (there's even a `wait` overload that takes a predicate, to make this formal). Start by figuring out what condition must become true before each thread can proceed further (I can't help you with that because, frankly, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thanks for the help. I added wait in worker, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. Posting here for reference.

`worker` waits for `manager` to consume the work result. And `manager` waits for both `worker`s to finish one day work.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

class Factory{

public:
    Factory() {
        work = 0; 
        workHours[0] = 0; 
        workHours[1] = 0;
    };
    void manager();

private:
    std::thread threads[2];
    std::mutex m_lock;
    std::condition_variable cond[2];
    std::condition_variable condMan;
    bool resFetch[2];
    bool resAvailable[2];

    int work;               // Shared across threads
    int workHours[2];       // One var for each thread

    int totalWorkHours;

    void worker(int id);
    void boss(int work, int workHours);
};

void Factory::worker(int id)
{
    cout<< id <<" Started Working "<<endl;
    for (int day = 0; day<365; day++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ m_lock };
        while(!resFetch[id])
            condMan.wait(lck);

        resFetch[id] = false;

        work++;
        workHours[id]++;
        cout << id << " working " << endl;
        resAvailable[id] = true;
        cond[id].notify_one();
        lck.unlock();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}

void Factory::manager()
{
    int wHrs0, wHrs1;

    threads[0] = std::thread([&](Factory *fac) { fac->worker(0); }, this);
    threads[1] = std::thread([&](Factory *fac) { fac->worker(1); }, this);

    for (;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ m_lock };

        resFetch[0] = true;
        resFetch[1] = true;

        condMan.notify_all();

        while(!resAvailable[0])
            cond[0].wait(lck);
        cout << "Worker0 workHours : " << workHours[0] << "  Total Work : " << work << endl;
        wHrs0 = workHours[0];
        resAvailable[0] = false;

        while (!resAvailable[1])
            cond[1].wait(lck);
        cout << "Worker1 workHours : " << workHours[1] << "  Total Work : " << work << endl;
        wHrs1 = workHours[1];
        resAvailable[1] = false;

        lck.unlock();

        totalWorkHours = wHrs0 + wHrs1;

        cout << "Both Workers Worked one day" << endl;
        boss(work, totalWorkHours);
    }
}

void Factory::boss(int work, int workHours)
{
    cout << "I am not Happy with just " << work << " amount of work in damn " << workHours << " Hrs " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Factory nike;
    nike.manager();

    //wait for keypress
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```